# Module development in enterprise edition

Tags: magento2, module, magento-enterprise

I have developed a module in community edition . 
Inside the folder `app/code/` i did my code it is working fine.
I have a doubt. is my module working fine in enterprise edition without any change ? or shall i need to change my module code to support enterprise edition?
If code need to change pls share url for module development for enterprise edition for magento 2.

Comment: It depends on what your code does.